# Caliburn Micro WinRT Navigation and Conductors

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a WinRT app which is up and running nicely using the caliburn.micro INavigationService (FrameAdapter). The problem is all of the pages in my app are full pages and they repeat a lot of view xaml markup. What I would like to do would be to have more of a "MasterPages" type of architecture where I have a shell view which defines the main layout and contains a ContentControl and uses the Conductor pattern to switch out the contents of the ContentControl. I have had success with this sort of architecture in the past with WPF and Silverlight so I assume it is possible in WinRT.

The problem is there seems to be a disconnect between the navigation infrastructure (using the FrameAdapter) and the Conductor infrastructure using a ContentControl bound to the ActiveItem of the conductor (like the SimpleNavigation sample).

In the conductor scenario I use ActivateItem:

```
ActivateItem(new MyViewModel());
```

but with the INavigationService I use NavigateToViewModel:

```
navigationService.NavigteToViewModel<MyViewModel>();
```

and the two don't seem to be connected as far as I can tell.

One idea I had was to create a ConductorNavigationService which implements INavigationService and basically handles the creation and activation of the child screens. While it seems possible it doesn't seem very straight forward so I figured I would check to see if there is an already supported way to do this in caliburn.micro.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out dude? I had a look at putting some stuff together in WPF but it would be just too much work to mock it up for a quick answer

Comment: I never figured out how to get it working but I have changed my design in such a way that I have decided to not implement the master page scenario for now. If you do end up adding a solution I will verify it works and accept the answer. Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 3):

Ok my understanding might be a little strained as I've not used WinRT or the `INavigationService` but I assume `Frame` is part of RT and `INavigationService` provides viewmodel resolution and navigation for the frames.

My other assumption is that your frame is a bit like your conductor already, and when you call 'Navigate()' on the frame, it just replaces the content of the frame with the newly specified content. If this is the case then CM is doing view first resolution for viewmodels.

Since you want to go the conductor route, it sounds like you want to ditch the CM implementation of `INavigationService` and just roll your own to handle the `INavigationService` navigation methods (e.g. skip the `Frame`s `Navigate()` method).

A quick look at the CM source reveals that all `NavigationService` is doing is handling the `Navigate` events on the frame and then doing VM resolution and setting up the view (something that conductor probably already does). All you would need to do is ensure that your `INavigationService` implementation just loads the specified view into the shell instead of navigating the frame

You could just need to steal the constructor code for `NavigationService` and change the implementation of `Navigate()`, then just call `ActivateItem(x)` on your shell where x is the instance of the VM. CM will take care of the rest (I think CM boostrapper will already setup your root 'Frame' too so you shouldn't need to worry about that).

e.g.

An implementation may look more like this (bear in mind this is just something I thrown together and may be barefaced lies!):

```
public class NewFrameAdapter : INavigationService
{
    private readonly Frame frame;
    private readonly IConductActiveItem shell;
    private event NavigatingCancelEventHandler ExternalNavigatingHandler = delegate { };

    public NewFrameAdapter(Frame frame)
    {
        this.frame = frame;

        // Might want to tighten this up as it makes assumptions :)
        this.shell = (frame as FrameworkElement).DataContext as IConductActiveItem;
    }

    public bool Navigate(Type pageType)
    {
        // Do guardclose and deactivate stuff here by looking at shell.ActiveItem
        // e.g.
        var guard = shell.ActiveItem as IGuardClose;

        if (guard != null)
        {
            var shouldCancel = false;
            guard.CanClose(result => { shouldCancel = !result; });

            if (shouldCancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        // etc

        // Obviously since the guard is probably async (assume it is, if not you are ok to continue!) you'd have to not call this code right 
        // here but I've just stuck it in here as an example

        // edit: looking at the code above (the guard code) it looks like this is all sync so the below code should be fine

        // You might get away with calling shell.ActivateItem(pageType) as I'm not sure
        // if the viewmodel binder in RT would resolve this all for you, but if it doesnt...

        // Init the view and then resolve the VM type
        ViewLocator.InitializeComponent(pageType);

        var viewModel = ViewModelLocator.LocateForView(pageType);

        // Activate the VM in the shell)
        shell.ActivateItem(viewModel);
    }
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to roll this your own way. Does this help you at all?

Then your XAML would be pretty simple:

```
<Frame blah blah>
  <SomeStaticContent />
  <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" /> <!-- The dynamic bit... -->
  <SomeMoreStaticContent />
</Frame>
```

I'm thinking that this will probably be a hybrid of view-first and viewmodel-first since your root `Frame` will be using view-first, and your conductor will be using `ActivateItem()` which takes a viewmodel and then resolves the view when the binder kicks in, but if my assumptions are ok, it should work

Comment: Thanks for the anwer! I have tried this approach but haven't quite been able to get it to work. Getting a reference to the Frame needed to change out the child views is proving to be difficult. Also getting a reference to the DataContext isn't proving too straight forward either.

Comment: I'll put something together in WPF and see if I can get it working similarly - I'm only on Win7 so afaik I can't use WinRT. If I can get something working in WPF I'm sure it can provide you with a starting point. I'll try and mock the Frame and Page classes